# Mina's Whenever integration. How do you set the "whenever_name"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever, mina

According to [this file](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina/blob/master/lib/mina/whenever.rb) it looks like I should be able to set the "whenever_name" to create a custom namespace for my cron jobs. I read mina's documentation on whenever as found [here](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina#modules-whenever). It does not mention how to set a custom namespace aka "whenever_name" for my jobs.

Their documentation outlines the basic usage for the rake tasks:

```
require 'mina/whenever'
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do
    ...
  to :launch do
    invoke :'whenever:update'
  end
end
```

So how do I specifiy the whenever_name when I call the rake task? Is there some configuration somewhere that I need to do?

The whenever.rb has some things to say about how to set whenever_name, but the provided documentation isn't enough for me to make the needed change. The comment tells me that I can overwrite the domain variable in either deploy.rb or schedule.rb. What is the syntax for overwriting that variable?

```
# ## Settings
# Any and all of these settings can be overriden in your `deploy.rb`.

# ### whenever_name
# Override the default name used by Whenever when clearing,
# updating or writing the crontab file.

namespace :whenever do
  # NOTE: setting this as a lambda to allow the user to override
  # the domain variable at any time in their schedule.rb file
  name = lambda { whenever_name || "#{domain}_#{rails_env}" }
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. In deploy.rb add the following line:

```
set :whenever_name, 'production'
```

Just had to take a step back use the brain I was given.